# Kube-proxy iptables block port 443 outbound when applied. Can curl my kibana instance on port 443 before kube-proxy rules are applied just fine

Tags: kubernetes, iptables, kube-proxy

When kube-proxy iptables rules are NOT applied, I can run:
curl -k https://kibana.default.svc.cluster.local:443/api/status

But, as soon as the kube-proxy rules automatically apply, I can no longer curl the url.  Here are the rules that the kube-proxy applies.  I tried deleting some of them that looked like they may be dropping, but no luck.  Anyone see any rules that may be causing this?  I assume one or more of the rules that are added, but not sure.  Any help is appreciated.